# How to put variables into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, element

I am making a Basketball Scoreboard that can determine the winner of the game in each quarter and the the main game.
How can i store the values of my variables in an array?
I want to put the values of "Q1teamOne, Q2teamOne, Q3teamOne, Q4teamOne" in an array and also the values of "Q1teamTwo, Q2teamTwo, Q3teamTwo ,Q4teamTwo" or make them elements of an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string Team1;
string Team2;
double OTscore1;
double OTscore2;
int Q1teamOne, Q2teamOne, Q3teamOne, Q4teamOne; 
int Q1teamTwo, Q2teamTwo, Q3teamTwo ,Q4teamTwo;
int Q2TeamOneTotal, Q3TeamOneTotal, Q4TeamOneTotal;
int Q2TeamTwoTotal, Q3TeamTwoTotal, Q4TeamTwoTotal;
double teamOneScore[4];
double teamTwoScore[4];
int index;
double sumOne, sumTwo;

cout << "BASKETBALL SCOREBOARD:\n" << endl;
cout << "Enter Team 1 name: ";
getline (cin, Team1);
cout << "Enter Team 2 name: ";
getline (cin, Team2);

//FIRST QUARTER

cout << "\nQUARTER 1:\n\n";
cout << "Team " << Team1 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q1teamOne;

cout << "Team " << Team2 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q1teamTwo;

if (Q1teamOne > Q1teamTwo)
    {
        cout <<"****" << "Team " << Team1 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q1teamOne < Q1teamTwo)
    {
        cout <<"****" << Team2 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q1teamOne = Q1teamTwo)
{
    cout <<"****We Have a Tie!!****\n\n";
}


//SECOND QUARTER
cout << "\nQUARTER 2:\n\n";
cout << "Team " << Team1 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q2teamOne;
Q2TeamOneTotal = Q1teamOne + Q2teamOne;
cout <<"Total Score: "<< Q2TeamOneTotal <<endl;;

cout << "Team " << Team2 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q2teamTwo;
Q2TeamTwoTotal = Q1teamTwo + Q2teamTwo;
cout <<"Total Score: " << Q2TeamTwoTotal;


if (Q2TeamOneTotal > Q2TeamTwoTotal)
    {
        cout <<"\n****" << Team1 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q2TeamOneTotal < Q2TeamTwoTotal)
    {
        cout <<"\n****" << Team2 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q2TeamOneTotal = Q2TeamTwoTotal)
{
    cout <<"\n****We Have a Tie!!****\n\n";
}


//THIRD QUARTER
cout << "\nQUARTER 3:\n\n";
cout << "Team " << Team1 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q3teamOne;
Q3TeamOneTotal = Q1teamOne + Q2teamOne + Q3teamOne;
cout <<"Total Score: "<< Q3TeamOneTotal <<endl;;

cout << "Team " << Team2 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q3teamTwo;
Q3TeamTwoTotal = Q1teamTwo + Q2teamTwo + Q3teamTwo;
cout <<"Total Score: " << Q3TeamTwoTotal;


if (Q3TeamOneTotal > Q3TeamTwoTotal)
    {
        cout <<"\n****" << Team1 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q3TeamOneTotal < Q3TeamTwoTotal)
    {
        cout <<"\n****" << Team2 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q3TeamOneTotal = Q3TeamTwoTotal)
    {
    cout <<"\n****We Have a Tie!!****\n\n";
    }

//FOURTH QUARTER

cout << "\nQUARTER 4:\n\n";
cout << "Team " << Team1 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q4teamOne;
Q4TeamOneTotal = Q1teamOne + Q2teamOne + Q3teamOne + Q4teamOne;
cout <<"Total Score: "<< Q4TeamOneTotal <<endl;

cout << "Team " << Team2 << " Score: ";
cin  >> Q4teamTwo;
Q4TeamTwoTotal = Q1teamTwo + Q2teamTwo + Q3teamTwo + Q4teamTwo;
cout <<"Total Score: " << Q4TeamTwoTotal;


    if (Q4TeamOneTotal > Q4TeamTwoTotal)
    {
        cout <<"\n****" << Team1 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q4TeamOneTotal < Q4TeamTwoTotal)
    {
        cout <<"\n****" << Team2 << " is Leading.****\n\n";
    }
else if (Q4TeamOneTotal = Q4TeamTwoTotal)
    {
    cout <<"\n****We Have a Tie!!****\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: How about `std::array<int, 4> teamOneArray;`? And you already have arrays for the score, meaning you already know how to make arrays, so what is your problem?

Comment: yeah i know how to make arrays, but how do i put my variable values in the "teamOneScore" array?

Comment: You should be using `vector` instead of arrays. That is the C++ way to store collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

teamOneScore[ 0 ] = Q1teamOne;

teamOneScore[ 1 ] = Q2teamOne;

teamOneScore[ 2 ] = Q3teamOne;

teamOneScore[ 3 ] = Q4teamOne;

teamTwoScore[ 0 ] = Q1teamTwo;

teamTwoScore[ 1 ] = Q2teamTwo;

teamTwoScore[ 2 ] = Q3teamTwo;

teamTwoScore[ 3 ] = Q4teamTwo;

But consider:

the arrays teamOneScore and teamTwoScore are arrays of double and your scores are int, so:

- change the type of the arrays to be ints or
- cast the assignment as: teamOneScore[ 0 ] = static_cast< double >( Q1teamOne );

Also, just for your information, this comparison is not correct:

else if (Q4TeamOneTotal = Q4TeamTwoTotal)

It should be:

else if (Q4TeamOneTotal == Q4TeamTwoTotal)

As a final note, you can use the arrays to store the scores from the cin and avoid the use of the Q1teamOne, ... vars.

Comment: I followed your advice and used the cin to store my values, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

For example

```
#include <functional>

//...


std::reference_wrapper<int> teamOne[] = { Q1teamOne, Q2teamOne, Q3teamOne, Q4teamOne };

std::reference_wrapper<int> teamTwo[] = { Q1teamTwo, Q2teamTwo, Q3teamTwo ,Q4teamTwo };
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int Q1teamOne, Q2teamOne, Q3teamOne, Q4teamOne;
    std::reference_wrapper<int> teamOne[] = 
    { 
        Q1teamOne, Q2teamOne, Q3teamOne, Q4teamOne 
    };

    int i = 0;
    for ( auto &x : teamOne ) x.get() = i++; 

    for ( const auto &x : teamOne ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3
```

Or if the link between the original values and the array is not need then you could write simply

```
double teamOneScore[] = { Q1teamOne, Q2teamOne, Q3teamOne, Q4teamOne };
```

Also you could use initializer list in the range based for statement without declaring any array. For example

```
for ( int x : { Q1teamOne, Q2teamOne, Q3teamOne, Q4teamOne } ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```